# Unity Game crash

Tags: unity-game-engine, addmodelerror

This error gives me when I open the app, everything worked until I implemented the ad system. The ids are correct, what can I be doing wrong? I followed tutorials

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

---

- The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
- should follow the instructions here:                                       *
- https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
- to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
- Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
- https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *

---

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7613)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6960)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:257)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1982)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8037)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

---

- The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
- should follow the instructions here:                                       *
- https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
- to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
- Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
- https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *

---

```
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzek.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@22.2.0:26)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@22.2.0:1)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7608)
... 10 more
```

the ids are fine. I can't find the problem